# Greyscale on Miui

Tags: xiaomi, miui, developer-options

I have a Xiaomi MI6 with MIUI pro installed on it. I tried to set the screen to monochrome from the developer settings, but every time I lock the phone and unlock it, the screen returns in colors.
It seems it is a bug of MIUI 9, is there an app that overrides this setting?